# How to get string after 3 slash in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I'm having difficulties to find a way of getting the `string` before the last slash in `excel 2007` formula.

```
https://www.example.com/text13611283/url_complement
```

The string I need is this: **text13611283**

Comment: What are you implementing? Formula or vba code?

Comment: @Light Formula. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this task based on input value
Case 1: you can Delimit the column by using menu "DATA/Text to Columns"

Case 2: Assuming your text is in A2 Cell the formula in B2 will be "=LEFT(MID(A2,FIND("/",A2,10)+1,100),FIND("/",MID(A2,FIND("/",A2,10)+1,100),1)-1)"

Answer (score 2):

### The String Between the Last Two Occurrences of a Slash (/) in Cell `A1`

**Formula**

```
=MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1))+1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1))-1)
```

**How?**

[image]

**How Formulas**

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))
=FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1)
=FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1))
=MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1))+1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1))-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),IF(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,255))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,255))-1)*99),99)),4)
```

- Replace each `/` with 99 spaces
- Using `MID`, create an array of each 99-space separated element in the string

  - `=IF(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,255))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,255))-1)*99)` creates an array to be used for the `start` argument of the `MID` function.  It returns an array of `{1,99,198,297,...}`
- `TRIM` to get rid of the extra spaces
- `INDEX` to extract the correct element.  In this case, it would be `4`.

[image]

Comment: How could one express the `4` with something like `'99-space separated elements'.Count - 1` or `'99 spaces'.Count` to make it work for more slashes contained in the initial string?
`

Comment: @VBasic2008 It will work as is for many slashes.  You use the `row` argument to the Index function to select which you want to return.  So you merely change the `4` at the end to whichever element you want returned.  (by the way, in Excel O365 you could use `SEQUENCE` instead of the long `ROW(INDEX...` sub formula.

Comment: But I want the element `between the last two slashes` and I don't know which one it will be because I have a different number of slashes in various cells. I remembered it: `LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Exactly. If you are going to count from the end, the last will be `=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))+1`, and just subtract one for the next to last, etc.